# Facebook plugin does not work properly on my website

Tags: facebook, plugins, xfbml, facepile

I'm trying to include the Facepile (one of Facebook's social plugins) on my website, but obviously without success:

- The Facepile does not show up.
- Firebug shows the generated code as inactive/gray.
- Firebug's Network plugin shows 3 HTTP requests to Facebook resources, they all seem to be ok.
- JavaScript is on.
- I used Firefox, but Google Chrome behaves just the same way.

The stripped down HTML looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=333311513469576";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        
        <fb:facepile href="http://www.facebook.com/umdiewelt" app_id="333311513469576" max_rows="1" width="300"></fb:facepile>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this?